# Elastic Search Multiple fields filter

Tags: elasticsearch

when it comes to elasticsearch, i am new to it. That's why, my question is if i'd like to filter multiple fields, would aggregate might solve the problem? or what should i use?

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
           { "term" : {"shop_slug" : "sharkys-dhammazedi.6326"}}, 
                    { "term" : 
{"slug" : "anchovy-essence"}}

          ]
        }
      }
 }
}}
```

HERE Is The Mapping

```
"product_catalogue": {
"mappings": {
"products": {
"properties": {
"buy_online": {
"type": "long"
},
"category": {
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "long"
},
"name": {
"type": "string"
},
"slug": {
"type": "string"
},
"tree": {
"properties": {
"2": {
"type": "string"
},
"3": {
"type": "string"
},
"5": {
"type": "string"
},
"10": {
"type": "string"
},
"11": {
"type": "string"
},
"12": {
"type": "string"
},
"13": {
"type": "string"
},
"14": {
"type": "string"
},
"15": {
"type": "string"
},
"16": {
"type": "string"
},
"17": {
"type": "string"
},
"18": {
"type": "string"
},
"19": {
"type": "string"
},
"20": {
"type": "string"
},
"21": {
"type": "string"
},
"22": {
"type": "string"
},
"23": {
"type": "string"
},
"24": {
"type": "string"
},
"25": {
"type": "string"
},
"26": {
"type": "string"
},
"27": {
"type": "string"
},
"28": {
"type": "string"
},
"29": {
"type": "string"
},
"30": {
"type": "string"
},
"31": {
"type": "string"
},
"32": {
"type": "string"
},
"33": {
"type": "string"
},
"34": {
"type": "string"
},
"35": {
"type": "string"
},
"36": {
"type": "string"
},
"37": {
"type": "string"
},
"38": {
"type": "string"
},
"39": {
"type": "string"
},
"40": {
"type": "string"
},
"41": {
"type": "string"
},
"42": {
"type": "string"
},
"43": {
"type": "string"
},
"46": {
"type": "string"
},
"62": {
"type": "string"
},
"72": {
"type": "string"
},
"73": {
"type": "string"
},
"74": {
"type": "string"
},
"75": {
"type": "string"
},
"77": {
"type": "string"
},
"137": {
"type": "string"
},
"139": {
"type": "string"
},
"140": {
"type": "string"
},
"141": {
"type": "string"
}
}
}
}
},
"click_collect": {
"type": "long"
},
"company_id": {
"type": "string"
},
"company_name": {
"type": "string"
},
"company_slug": {
"type": "string",
"index": "not_analyzed"
},
"condition": {
"type": "string"
},
"created_at": {
"type": "date",
"format": "dateOptionalTime"
},
"currency_iso": {
"type": "string"
},
"delivery_available": {
"type": "boolean"
},
"delivery_type": {
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "long"
},
"name": {
"type": "string"
},
"pivot": {
"properties": {
"deliverytype_id": {
"type": "long"
},
"pricing": {
"type": "string"
},
"shop_id": {
"type": "long"
}
}
}
}
},
"description": {
"type": "string",
"analyzer": "snowball"
},
"group_id": {
"type": "string"
},
"image_url": {
"type": "string"
},
"listed_shop": {
"type": "integer"
},
"location": {
"type": "geo_point"
},
"mainPhoto": {
"type": "string"
},
"mm_description": {
"type": "string"
},
"mm_title": {
"type": "string"
},
"postcode": {
"type": "string"
},
"prices": {
"properties": {
"retail": {
"properties": {
"converted": {
"properties": {
"currencyIso": {
"type": "string"
},
"decimal": {
"type": "string"
},
"formatted": {
"type": "string"
}
}
},
"original": {
"properties": {
"currencyIso": {
"type": "string"
},
"decimal": {
"type": "string"
},
"formatted": {
"type": "string"
}
}
}
}
}
}
},
"shop_category": {
"type": "long"
},
"shop_id": {
"type": "long"
},
"shop_name": {
"type": "string"
},
"shop_slug": {
"type": "string",
"index": "not_analyzed"
},
"shop_stock_count": {
"type": "integer"
},
"shop_type": {
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "long"
},
"name": {
"type": "string"
}
}
},
"slug": {
"type": "string"
},
"title": {
"type": "string",
"analyzer": "snowball"
},
"user_stock_count": {
"type": "integer"
},
"variant": {
"properties": {
"Colour": {
"type": "string"
},
"Disk Space": {
"type": "string"
},
"Length": {
"type": "string"
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

This query didn't seems to work out . Infact, it only filter one of the fields but can't resolve to filter both fields which is shop_slug and slug. Please kindly answer Thanks.

Comment: Please share mappings of `shop_slug` and `slug`

Comment: Here you are above is the mapping of my elastisearch

Comment: try with `slug` and indexed as `not_analyzed`. As slug is not a keyword field and it contains characters other than alphanum.

Comment: finally found my way out https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-query-strings.html